# Bulletproof show/hide animated boxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to achieve the following end result: On page load, there is a content box with a heading (or image, some element, etc). When you hover over this content box, the original content fades out, and is replaced by new content. Also, the box will enlarge via animation. On mouseout the content box will return to it's original state at page load by fading out the new content, fading in the old content, and returning the content box to it's original height.

What I have done does work, but it is not bulletproof. You can hover over the box, mouseout, and then hover over the box again and it will show the box at it's original height with the new content.

I'm trying to figure out a bulletproof way to do this and have it work in IE8+/Chrome/Safari/Firefox. There must be some simple method that I am overlooking to complete this and I'm having some trouble finding a great way to do it.

I've attempted adding an animated class to the element, which is removed when the animation is completed, and then using `setTimeout` to check if the class is still there after 400 milliseconds, but I was having some trouble with that method working in IE8.

Not really sure of anything else I can try and if anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate the assistance.

The provided JSFiddle provides a basic idea of what I am trying to do.. I'm just looking for a bulletproof way to do it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur78U/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to use the jQuery `fadeTo()` method.

This ensures that the animation will complete and not get stuck as it did in my example.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur78U/2/